# What the problem with selenium and proxy on php?

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver

This PHP code is intended to retrieve the contents of a web page using a proxy server. While the proxy server is confirmed working via CURL, when used in the code, the request returns no content. The page screenshot also comes out empty. The desired page content is not being retrieved. What is the problem?

```php
<?php

use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\WebDriverCapabilityType;
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverExpectedCondition;

$proxyAddress = 'user:password@127.0.0.1:49001';
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
// Disable accepting SSL certificates
$capabilities->setCapability(WebDriverCapabilityType::ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
// Create an instance of ChromeOptions:
$chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
$chromeOptions->addArguments(['--headless', '--no-sandbox', '--disable-gpu', '--proxy-server=http://' . $proxyAddress]);

$chromeOptions->setExperimentalOption('w3c', true);
$capabilities->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $chromeOptions);

$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create('http://127.0.0.1:9515', $capabilities);

$driver->get("https://site.....");
echo $driver->getPageSource();

$driver->takeScreenshot('/path/..../screen_123.jpg');

$driver->quit();
```

There are no errors present within the code. An empty response is being returned.

Comment: Remove the `headless` flag. Then you'll see what's happening in the browser. Be sure to run it on your local computer, e.g. your desktop.

Comment: Error: Unable to access site. But the proxy server is working. Tested on python it works. php does not work

Comment: Let's simplify your case. Open your Chrome, set the proxy server, and access your site. Does it show the website properly? How does your Python script work? also with the same logic? If possible please show the Python codes for comparison as well.